# Box characters in nm-connection-editor using X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, xorg

I have a **Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux ARM** (latest) and a **laptop running Ubuntu 14**. I am using **NetworkManager** to configure the network on the Raspberry Pi, and I wanted to access the connection editor GUI by **forwarding X11** over an SSH connection from my laptop. However, when I run `nm-connection-editor` in the session, 
[the resulting dialog has box characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ygYy.png). I am not sure whether this problem also occurs if I run the program on a display connected to the Pi's HDMI port; I am currently unable to check for such a case.

How can I diagnose and fix this problem? Or, has someone else had the same problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at this [blog post](http://robert.penz.name/354/how-to-fix-the-font-for-virt-manager-via-x-forwarding/). Essentially, I needed to install some fonts on my Raspberry Pi. The packages `ttf-dejavu` and `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` worked for me.